# Как передать в контроллер значение из списка select

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Не ожидал наткнуться на проблему в таком вопросе и тем не менее. Вот мое представление :

```
<select name="EdLevel">
   <option value="">Высшее - Бакалавр</option>
   <option value="">Высшее - Магистр</option>
   <option value="">Кандидат Наук</option>
   <option value="">Доктор Наук</option>
   <option value="">Неоконченное высшее</option>
   <option value="">Среднее Специальное</option>
   <option value="small_form_wanted">Среднее</option>
</select>
```

И есть модель с полем :

```
    public string EdLevel { get; set; }
```

Каждый раз при попытке отправить значение из списка, в контроллер приходит null. Хотя если я вместо списка использую обычный `input`, например так :

```
<input  type="text" name="EdLevel"/>
```

то проблем не возникает. Видимо трудность именно в контролле `select`. Как тип данных в моделе пробовал не строку а `SelectListItem` - результат тот же. Вопрос - как же все таки передать выбранное значение ?

Comment: `<option value=""` -> `<option value="1"`

Comment: @Igor а все было просто. спасибо больше вопросов нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Значение, которое передается на сервер с данными формы для именованного элемента `select`, берется из атрибута `value` выбранного элемента `option`:

```
<select name="EdLevel">
   <option value="1">Высшее - Бакалавр</option>
   <option value="2">Высшее - Магистр</option>
   <option value="3">Кандидат Наук</option>
   ...
```